# ffmpeg playback on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, sdl, playback

I managed to compile ffmpeg libs for Android and i am able to load them in my jni Android app. Now started calling the ffmpeg functions and following the online tutorials. I read there that I need also SDL port for Android in order to render audio/video.

I have looked at libsdl and it seems quite complex to use on Android, especially since I just need sequential render of audio/video media samples, is there some simpler solution (with examples) how to render the decoded buffers? Should I pass decoded media buffers from frrmpeg back to java for rendering?

If I have to use SDL, is there some tutorial how to easy integrate it on Android with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

There are some suggestions:

The ffmpeg decodes video pix_fmt is yuv420p, 
you need to convert it to BGR32 or RGB565. 
If you plan use the Bitmap and SurfaceView to render video frame.

If your devices Android 2.2+, there are c functions to copy bitmap data to Bitmap.
By geting the pointer using AndroidBitmap_lockPixels and AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels.

If your devices don't support that way, 
you can put binary data to ByteBuffer and use Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer().

If your SurfaceView will scale larger, you should handle anti-alias problem:

[Can u ? How to anti alias for SurfaceView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846115/can-u-how-to-anti-alias-for-surfaceview-in-android)

If OpenGL is the prefered solution, 
GLThread may consume more cpu time, use draw on dirty is better.

The topic is so interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think dolphin-player (http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/) for android used libSDL